# Return subject only for subscription

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable, subject

my question is regarding returning a reference to a subject without allowing the receiver to do .next() on the subject.

For instance, I have a service which contains a subject and can trigger new events on the subject

```
class ExampleService {
  private exampleSubject = new Subject<boolean>;

  // Ideally the only way to call next on the subject
  doNext() {
    this.exampleSubject.next(true);
  }

  getSubject() {
    // Ideally returning a reference to the subject but only with the 
    // ability to subscribe and listen for events, not to call .next()
    return this.exampleSubject;
  }
}
```

Again, what I am looking for is a way to have other components call this service and get the subject but only be able to subscribe and listen for changes, they should not be able to make changes.

```
ExampleService.getSubject().subscribe(() => {
  //do something 
}) // ok
ExampleService.getSubject().next(true) // error/not allowed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The officially recommended way of doing this (assuming you're using TypeScript) is to force retype the Subject to an Observable (Subject is Observable like any other):

```
class ExampleService {
  private exampleSubject = new Subject<boolean>();
  observable$: Observable<boolean> = this.exampleSubject;

  ...
}
```

Now `observable$` can be public because it's just a regular Observable. TypeScript won't allow you to call eg `ExampleService.observable$.next()` because this method doesn't exist on Observables.

If you're using just JavaScript you can use `exampleSubject.asObservable()` to return Observable from a Subject.

This discussion on RxJS's GitHub is also relevant: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/2408

Comment: Thanks! This is what I am looking for. .asObservable() combined with the Observable type is perfect!